# SQL set column to specified value, based on value match from linked records in a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying a simple SQL update in Microsoft SQL Server. I need to set a column to a specified value, based on a value match from linked records in a joined table. Using the SQL below I get 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword INNER'. What do I need to do, and what's the explanation of why I need to do it that way instead of how I'm trying it here:

```
UPDATE
    Core.Booking
INNER JOIN
    Core.BookingExtended be
    ON be.BookingId = BookingId
SET StandardFee = 11.50
WHERE
    ServiceId = 618
    AND be.BookingDate >= '1-sep-2014'
    AND FeeId = 7900
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper syntax for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE b
    SET StandardFee = 11.50
    FROM Core.Booking b INNER JOIN
         Core.BookingExtended be
         ON be.BookingId = b.BookingId
    WHERE ServiceId = 618 AND be.BookingDate >= '2014-09-01' AND FeeId = 7900;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all fields are used with alias while they exist in both tables. Try changing to this:

```
UPDATE bo
SET bo.StandardFee = 11.50
FROM
Core.Booking bo -- NEW ALIAS
INNER JOIN
    Core.BookingExtended be
    ON be.BookingId = bo.BookingId

WHERE
    bo.ServiceId = 618
    AND be.BookingDate >= '1-sep-2014'
    AND bo.FeeId = 7900
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier - this gives me Incorrect syntax near 'bo'.

Comment: Ok what is the message?

Comment: does your core.booking table contain bookingid?